# I want to print or pass name of a list to text() field but can't (just the name not the items)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
var categoryList = [hotDrinks , coldDrinks];
List<Item> hotDrinks = [Item(name:"hot chocolate" , contents: "milk-chocolate")] ;
List<Item> coldDrinks = [Item(name: "orange juice" , contents: "orange")] ;
print(categoryList[i].tostring())
```

but it just print an instance of each item like [instance of 'item']

Answer (score 0):

Override your Items toString method, example add the following method to the Item class

```
String toString() {
  return this.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This prints out 'hot chocolate'.  Hope it helps.

```dart
class Item{
  String name;
  String contents;
  
  Item({this.name, this.contents});
  
  String get nameStr => name;

}

main() {
  List<Item> hotDrinks = [Item(name:"hot chocolate" , contents: "milk-chocolate")] ;
  List<Item> coldDrinks = [Item(name: "orange juice" , contents: "orange")] ;

  var categoryList = [hotDrinks , coldDrinks];
  int i = 0;
  print(categoryList[i][0].nameStr);
}
```

Comment: yeah it prints 'hot chocolate ' but i wanna print "hotDrinks"